# How does one style an HTML 5 audio player such that it always shows the progress bar in its "hover" state?

Tags: css, html5-audio

I like to look at the native  player and see exactly how the song has progressed without having to hover over the progress bar of the player.

How does one style an HTML 5 audio player such that it always shows the progress bar in its mouse "hover" state?

Ideally, I'd like to just style the player with CSS. I can't seem to find how to do this.  Any of you guys or gals out there know how to do this?

Comment: To my knowledge it's not possible. mozilla.org has this to say: *"You can style the default controls with properties that affect the block as a single unit, so for example you can give it a border and border-radius, padding, margin, etc. You can't however style the individual components inside the audio player (e.g. change the button size or icons, change the font, etc.), and the controls are different across the different browsers."*

Comment: More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#styling_with_css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  Much appreciations.  Too bad they don't let you style the components inside of the player.  Maybe they'll allow that someday.